# Creating two geom_tile layers on ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm trying to represent two variables (crime and rent prices) on a ggmap using geom_tile. Individually, both maps look great.

```
heat_crime = ggmap(cmap) + 
        geom_tile(data = LatLonCounts_crime, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, alpha = Frequency), fill="red") + 
        scale_alpha(range = c(0, 0.8))

heat_price = ggmap(cmap) + 
        geom_tile(data = mean_price_per_bedroom_per_tile, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, alpha = mean_price), fill="blue") + 
        scale_alpha(range = c(0, 0.8))
```

[image: heat_price]

I would like to add both geom_tiles on the same map. I've tried this:

```
heat_all = ggmap(cmap) + 
        geom_tile(data = LatLonCounts_crime, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, alpha = Frequency), fill="red") + 
        scale_alpha(range = c(0, 0.8)) + 
        geom_tile(data = mean_price_per_bedroom_per_tile, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, alpha = mean_price), fill="blue") + 
        scale_alpha(range = c(0, 0.8))
```

[image: heat_all]

But the geom_tile overlay then combines the price and crime variable into one (as becomes clear when you look at the legend).

How can I keep both variables fully separated and show them both on the same ggmap?

Comment: On the contrary, it appears both geom_tiles are being plotted as separate layers, hence the fact that the legend title is "Frequency", which is the layer added first. Try adding `show.legend = TRUE` to both calls to `geom_tile` to confirm whether this is the case. Also, if you could post some example data, it would be easier to help :).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!